# SQL-инъекция

Tags: mysql, безопасность

На необходимом мне PHP-сайте выявил вывод ошибок на страницу результатов поиска:
При вводе поискового запроса начинающегося с одинарной кавычки, напрмер "**'something**"
вместо результатов поиска выводится следующие:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/u851536963/public_html/view_search.php on line 69
>
> Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошёл! Напишите об этом администратору email@bk.ru
> Код ошибки:
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server  version for the right syntax to use near
>
> ```
>  'something%' OR description LIKE'%'something%' OR author LIKE'%'something%''
>  at line 1`
> ```

Как это можно использовать для проведения SQL-инъекции?

*Задача абсолютно учебная и не несёт никаких незаконных целей!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сработало, чтобы вывести все возможные результаты поиска:

```
 %' or '1'='1
```

Answer (score 0):

Используя UNION, можно объединить разные запросы и подобрать sql запрос так, что выдаст данные из базы, например хеши паролей, поэтому лучше думать не про то, как его можно использовать, а про то, как ее прикрыть.

Comment: привести пример кода можете?

Comment: зависит от движка, но грубый пример ввести поисковый запрос - 
     ' UNION SELECT * FROM `users` limit 0,1 /*

Скорее всего выдаст ошибку, но перебирая запрос, поля и таблицы, можно получить искомый результат, такчто закрывайте не мешкая